# Cancel button click highlight after showing UIActionView on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view that has a button which brings up a UIActionSheet pop up on click. If the user clicks cancel, the original button that brought up the action sheet is still highlighted as if it is being clicked. How do I reset the state after user cancels the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about my false assumption that you were using UIButton. Here should be what you need:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //your implementation here
    ....

    //Then deselect the row so it quits the highlighted state
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That worked very well. Though I'm deselecting before I show the UIActionSheet, that works perfectly for my case since UIActionSheet opens up immediately giving user the click feel, rather than my work around disabling row highlight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the protocol methods to change the state of the button that was clicked:

```
@protocol UIActionSheetDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

// Called when a button is clicked. The view will be automatically dismissed after this call returns
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

// Called when we cancel a view (eg. the user clicks the Home button). This is not called when the user clicks the cancel button.
// If not defined in the delegate, we simulate a click in the cancel button
- (void)actionSheetCancel:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet;

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet;  // before animation and showing view
- (void)didPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet;  // after animation

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex; // before animation and hiding view
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;  // after animation

@end
```

Comment: Thanks diwup. But I'm having trouble about the "changing the state" of the button. What specifically I should set in the didDismissWithButtonIndex method. [UIButton resignFirstResponder] or something like that?

Comment: forgot to mention that the initial "button" that kicks off the UIActionSheet is actually a UItableviewcell. So, I just need to get rid of the blue color on that row.

Comment: @coder net: I assume you used UIButton, since UIButton is a subclass of UIControl, and UIControl has property called **(BOOL) highlighted**. I think you can set that property back to **NO** once you cancel your action sheet.

Comment: ok, I was able to do a work around similar to what you suggested. I set the cell.selectionStyle = NO; Now it does not change color when you click on the cell, but thats ok as it will bring up the UIActionSheet forcing the user to make a choice. I'll accept your answer anyway. Thanks for your help.